# OpenVPN Server TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)

Tags: tcp, udp, openvpn

I've been trying to set up an OpenVPN server on my Linux recently but I continuously get the same error every time I try to connect to my server.

My settings are like this:

```
proto tcp

port 443

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

user nobody

group nogroup

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA256


script-security 2

up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved

down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved

down-pre

dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
```

I have checked the settings on my server and local computer a million times and all of them are the same. Still don't know what I have to do about it. Thanks in advance! :*

```
Sat Nov 27 23:45:11 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 19 2021
Sat Nov 27 23:45:11 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
Sat Nov 27 23:45:11 2021 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Sat Nov 27 23:45:11 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]myserverip:443
Sat Nov 27 23:45:11 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
Sat Nov 27 23:45:11 2021 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]myserverip:443 [nonblock]
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]myserverip:443
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]myserverip:443
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Sat Nov 27 23:45:12 2021 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```